# Worklight connection issue when migrating from development environment to dev/test environment

Tags: connection, ibm-mobilefirst

I am coming across an urgent issue when doing migration from development environment to dev/test environment. I always get the error

> The server was unable to process the request from the application.
>   Please try again later.

*Note: the dev environment is ready (worklight console and application center). I can access them via two urls of ...:9080/worklight/console/ and ...:9080/applicationcenter/applications/Applications.html*

I saw the "Help-IBM Worklight" doc and followed steps it list, but it didn't work.

The steps I've taken:

1. change application-descriptor.xml's worklightServerRootURL to: http://www.test.com:9080/worklight
2. change  worklight.properties:

```
publicWorkLightHostname=www.test.com
# http or https
publicWorkLightProtocol = http
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=9080
publicWorkLightContext=/worklight
```

Followed by:

1. Build All and Deploy
2. Rename the MyTest.war file to worklight.war
   (I saw a .war file named "worklight.war" had been deployed, which is used for worklight console, I think.)

When I access the url "www.test.com:9080/worklight/apps/services/api/ISMD/android/" directly, I get the error:

> AuthenticationContext.getOrCreateAuthenticationContext()

Any help?

Comment: the war file is much more than Worklight Console, it contains worklight.properties and authenticationConfig.xml; you must re-deploy this .war file in your application server for your changes to take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention in your steps whether or not you have re-deployed the .war file.
You did not mention what is the application server you are running on in your dev/test environment.

The war file is much more than Worklight Console; it also contains worklight.properties and authenticationConfig.xml among other artifacts; you must re-deploy this .war file in your application server for your changes to take place.

In addition, [this APAR suggests a configuration issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM80510) when such an error is logged.
Try re-deployment first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Idan.

The application server: WebSphere.

My situation is that the Application Server environment is set up by another team, and the previous .war file is also deployed by that team. 

I read "this APAR suggests a configuration issue" you gave. I think it may be because I missed some configuration info in worklight.properties in my own .war file, such as: db connection.

Will try to re-deploy it. 
Thanks, again.

Comment: Idan, another question.
If the worklight console and application center have been available in dev/test environment, do I still need to re-deploy the .war file to application server?

Comment: the application center is a different entity than worklight. if you make such changes, you always need to re-deploy the .war file

Comment: So, if there are no any updates needed to worklight console and application center, and I just want to upload a new app or update an old one, I don't need to re-deploy the .war file. 
Is it correct?

Comment: If you want to update just the .wlapp, then .war file re-deployment is not required. If you make any changes in worklight.properties or authenticationConfig.xml or custom java and the like, you need to re-deploy your .war file.

Comment: OK. Then the strange problem is coming for me.
I upload the MyHybrid-all.wlapp to worklight console, and then upload a MyHybrid.apk to applicatoin center.
After used a real device set up my app, my app cannot connect to worklight server. And get the above error that the server was unable to...
Maybe, it is because of users access rights?

Comment: I don't know. You are not providing the error message the device gets. Open a new question. It is no longer in the scope of this questions, it's becoming too long.